# Can I set a maximum number of characters allowed in a label?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to have a label that, at most, can display one character, whether it be a letter or digit. So If I enter 10 into a text box and I want to display that in a label, it will only display 1 because the 0 makes it too long. And if I do like 812, then it will only display 8.

Comment: Can you just truncate the length when assigning the value to the label?

Comment: What have you tried? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly answers these questions, along with a detailed explanation that does as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the first character of the string you receive from the textbox:

```
string text = textbox.Text;
label.Content = text[0];
```